# Docker-compose volume creation for non-root user

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to create a docker image with docker-compose for my web application. My web application needs permissions to write files on file system.

My Dockerfile contains

```
# some other stuff
RUN addgroup -S web && adduser -S -g web web
USER web
```

I want to mount my current `.` directory to `/code` in docker container;

When I perform `docker-compose build` && `docker-compose up`, It occurs that my `/code` directory in container is owned for user "1000:1000", not my user that I created in Dockerfile.

```
version: '2'                                                                     

services:                                                                                           
  admin:                                                                         
    build:                                                                       
      context: .                                                                 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile                                                     
    command: python manage.py 0.0.0.0 8030                           
    volumes:                                                                     
    - .:/code                                                                    
    ports:                                                                       
     - 9000:8030                                                                 
    stdin_open: true                                                             
    tty: true                                                                                                                 
volumes:                                                                         
  .:                                                                             
    driver_opts:                                                                 
      o: uid=100,gid=65533
```

As you see, I tried to pass driver_opts with my user uid and gid parameters; but it didn't help.

My question is: what should I do to mount my directory `.` to `/code` in docker container privileges for user `web`?

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

docker version 17.09.0-ce

docker-compose version 1.8.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with:

`RUN addgroup -g 1000 web && \
  adduser -G web -g web -s /bin/sh -D web`

your user will be able to write to the mounted directory.

Comment: Yes, almost this. Solved this by setting up user uid and gid explicitly:  `RUN addgroup -S web -g 1000 && adduser -u 1000 -G web -D web`. It solved my problem with writing permissions. But it still not obvious for my why my volume always mounted owned by `1000:1000` and how can i change this

Comment: Your volume is mounted with 1000:1000 because this is your user on your host. Try `id -u ${users}`, which will give you your user id. A volume in a docker container is kind of an access to you host file system so you have the same user id in the volume as you have on you host file system.